# How to access subclass properties from superclass method (in C++)

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to understand how define a method in a base class (A), and be able to use it unmodified "as is" in derived subclasses while accessing the properties of the subclass.

In the example below is the idea is that `A1.print()` should return `1` (taking the *i* value from the derived class) not `0` (as it does here). I also don't want to have to copy/duplicate the "print" function verbatim to the subclass as it would be unnecessary to copy.

```
class A {
public:
  int i = 0;
  virtual void print(){
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
};

class A1 : public A {
public:
  int i = 1;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  A1 a1;
  printf("%d\n", a1.i);   // prints 1
  a1.print();             // prints 0
}
```

Comment: Why does `A1` shadow the `i` member of its base class? `A1` could just use (assign/read) the `i` of `A` instead of introducing an own member for this. (In this case, `print()` even doesn't need to be `virtual`. The sense of `virtual` is providing something that can be overloaded in derived classes but you didn't use that option.) Base classes shouldn't have knowledge of the derived classes, in general - that's breaking the principles of OOP. Instead, base classes may provide "doors" for derived classes - like e.g. a virtual member function.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Well the idea was to use subclasses to conveniently define properties instead of explicitly setting them in the constructors. Yes, I'm aware I'm not using print in the derived class, as I wanted to use it "as is" just with the properties of the derived class.

Comment: Please, note that your `class A1` has two members `i`: `A::i` and `A1::i`. There are rare cases where this could be intended but usually it's rather an accident.

Comment: Why not a constructor in `A` with `explicit A(int i = 0): i(i) { }` which then could be used in the derived class `A1`: `explicit A1(int i = 1): A(i) { }`? Please note that both constructors could act as default constructor as well (as I gave your default values to the parameters).

Comment: I wouldn't introduce shadowed members just to prevent the need of constructors... (beside of the other issues which you are facing).

Comment: And, to solve your literal issue, it's necessary to override `print()` in `A1`. (In this case, just copy/paste the `print()` of `A` to `A1`.)

Comment: Hmm, I would like to avoid passing **i** to the constructor as it is a property of the object (subclass) and will never change (in my real case). And copying the whole method to the subclass is not ideal either in the real case (to avoid code duplication) as it would be a larger function.

Comment: So, you could make your member `A::i` `const`: `const int i`. Happily, you still can initialize it in the constructor `A` like shown above (but any other attempt to assign something will be complained by the compiler). Please note, that a `const` member variable makes the assignment operators broken. If you intend to use them you have to provide customized operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a constructor with a default value for each class:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A(const int i = 0) : i(i) {}
    virtual void print() {...}

    int i;
};


class A1 : public A
{
  public:
    A1() : A() {}
    A1(int i) : A(i) {}
}
```

Then:

```
A1 a1{1};
printf("%d\n", a1.i);   // prints 1
a1.print();             // prints 1
```

And also:

```
A1 a1;
printf("%d\n", a1.i);   // prints 0
a1.print();             // prints 0
```